# How to find explicitly the Klein j-invariant

Tags: algebraic-geometry, galois-theory, rational-functions, mobius-transformation, cross-ratio

Let $K$ be a field, and let $K(x)$ be the associated field of rational functions. I want to find the subfield $L$ of $K(x)$ of the rational functions that are invariant under this set of transformations:
$$x\mapsto x$$
$$x\mapsto \frac{1}{x}$$
$$x\mapsto 1-x$$
$$x\mapsto \frac{x}{x-1}$$
$$x\mapsto \frac{1}{1-x}$$
$$x\mapsto 1-\frac{1}{x}$$
By Lüroth theorem I know that there exist a rational function $\ell(x)$ such that $L=K(\ell(x))$ and I know that I can take
$$\ell(x)=\frac{(x^2-x+1)^3}{x^2(x-1)^2}$$
In each book or lecture notes I have found, this object is only defined, and later is proved to be invariant, but I was interested in how to find it without too many calculations. Are there some references or can you give a hint? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: [A closely related older question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1332592/11619). I haven't looked at it closely enough, but I hope/suspect that you can rewrite the numerator of the generator I found in a form that fits this.